# trying to update user getting error Cannot POST /update-user

Tags: javascript, mongodb, post, backend, ejs

Hello when i try to update user on page i get error Cannot POST /update-user
cannot find there is a problem can someone see there is a mistake was done code below
[image]

index.js

```
$('#add_user').submit(function(event){
    alert("Informacija išsaugota!")
})

$('#update-user').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

let unindexed_array =$(this).serializeArray();
let data = {}
$.map(unindexed_array,function(n,i){
data[n['name']]= n['value']
})

console.log(data)

let request = {
    "url" : `http://localhost:3000/api/users/${data.id}`,
    "method" : "PUT",
    "data" : data
}

$.ajax (request).done(function(response){
    alert("Naudotojas Atnaujintas!")
})

})

if(window.location.pathname == "/"){
    $ondelete=$(".table tbody td a.delete");
    $ondelete.click(function(){
        let id = $(this).attr("data-id")
   
        let request = {
            "url" : `http://localhost:3000/api/users/${id}`,
            "method" : "DELETE",
   
        }
   
   if(confirm("Ar tikrai norite ištrinti įraša?")){
    $.ajax (request).done(function(response){
        alert("Naudotojas ištrintas!")
    location.reload()
    })
   }
   
    })

}
```

ROUTER.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router()

const services = require('../services/render')
const controller = require('../controller/controller')

/**
 * @description Root Route
 * @method GET/
 */

route.get('/',services.homeRoutes)
    
/**
 * @description add users
 * @method GET/ add-user
 */    

    route.get('/add-user',services.add_user)
        
/**
 * @description for update user
 * @method GET/  update-user
 */  

    route.get('/update-user',services.update_user)
    
    // API
    
    route.post('/api/users',controller.create);
    route.get('/api/users',controller.find);
    route.put('/api/users/:id',controller.update);
    route.delete('/api/users/:id',controller.delete);

    module.exports = route
```

_show.ejs

```
<%for(var i = 0; i <users.length; i++){%>

<tr>
    <td><%= i + 1%></td>
    <td><%=users[i].name%></td>
    <td><%=users[i].email%></td>
    <td><%=users[i].Lytis%></td>
    <td><%=users[i].status%></td>
    <td>
        <a href="/update-user?id=<%=users[i]._id%>" class="btn border-shadow update">
            <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></span>
        </a>
        <a class="btn border-shadow delete" data-id=<%=users[i]._id%>>
         <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-user-slash"></i></span>
     </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<%}%>
```

Try to search andchange some methods but nothing works and stuck now
its can be wrong ejs i gues . Or something else .
And how to consolelog all details coming from backend or from front end ?

Comment: If you are trying to POST to `update-user`, I think you need to allow post for that method:


    `route.post('/update-user',services.update_user)`

Answer (score 0):

`route.get('/update-user',services.update_user)`

Is defined as GET, but you're posting to it - Change to

`route.post('/update-user',services.update_user)`

```
$.ajax (request).done(function(response){

    console.log(response) <------------------------------------
    alert("Naudotojas Atnaujintas!")
})
```

Comment: i did what u said but i get Cannot GET /update-user added

Comment: // json app configuration
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

Comment: If you want both HTTP methods, you have to define both GET and POST - `route.get('/update-user',services.update_user)` *and* `route.post('/update-user',services.update_user)` - You might want different logic based on the HTTP method, defined in services.update_user

Answer (score 0):

change `get` to `post` in this line

```
route.get('/update-user',services.update_user)
```

to

```
route.post('/update-user',services.update_user)
```

because your submit is `post` method
and if need add `app.use(express.json())` and `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));` to express